# Basic Array Skills: Label Each Element

Tags: java, arrays

I have to perform the following basic skills with arrays: Here is a list of everything I had to do:

- a) Create an array x of doubles with an initializer list that contains the following values: 8, 4, 5, 21, 7, 9, 18, 2, and 100.
- b) Print the number of items in the array.
- c) Print the first array item.
- d) Print the last array item. Be careful to choose the right index.
- e) Use a standard for loop to print all the values in the array.
- f) Use a standard for loop to print all the values in the array with labels to indicate the location of each element, such as [0] = xx
- g) Use a standard for loop to print all the values in the array in reverse order.
- h) Use an enhanced for loop to print all the values in the array.

I am having a lot of trouble with f), I saw that you could label using "JLabel" which I did not learn in my class but I wasn't sure if it could be applied here, here is my code so far. If "JLabel" can't be used, what else would I be able to do? Any help will be appreciated, Thanks!!!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   double[] x = {8, 4, 5, 21, 7, 9, 18, 2, 100};
   double temp;
   System.out.println("The number of items in the array is " + x.length);
   System.out.println("The first array item is " + x[0]);
   System.out.println("The last array item is " + x[8]);

   for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
   {
       System.out.println(x[i] + " ");
   }


     //F
     //JLabel labels[] = new JLabel[8];
     //for (int i =  0; i < 9; i++)
     //{
     //labels[i] = new JLabel("Label" + i);
     //}

   for(int i =x.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
   {
       System.out.println(x[i] + " ");
   }

   for (double val : x)
   {
       System.out.println(val + " ");
   }

}
```

}

Comment: JLabel is part of Swing, a Java GUI framework, while nothing else in this app is. Are you sure this is the  approach you're supposed to take? Or are you just supposed to print out the  array index of each item?

Comment: I don't think the requester intends for you to use JLabels. My reading of the question is that you just need to provide some text with each println() that identifies which position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) is a Swing GUI component. It represents a text label in a GUI. It is not what you want to use here (although I can understand your attraction to the "Label" in its name -- but, you don't make ham with a hammer).

Your requirement is simply "print all the values in the array with labels to indicate the location of each element, such as `[0] = xx`". That is, "labels" in the [dictionary sense](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/label), not "labels" as in some explicit special "label" class.

It's simpler than you think, you may be over-complicating this! For example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i ++) {
   // 'i' is the index
   // 'x[i]' is the value
   System.out.println( /* fill this in */ );
}
```

I'll leave the details as an exercise to you. Hint: If `i==1` and `x[i]==42` then the output should be `[1] = 42`.

Comment: That helps, thanks!!! So it would be something like this:        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i ++)
       {
           System.out.println(i + " = " + x[i]);
       }

Comment: @DragonAge99 That seems reasonable. Try it!

Comment: The first of the outputs I got is "0 = 8.0" so it seems to be working, thanks for the help!!!